# Paypal not proceeding to receive the payment

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to make a donation through paypal using the [this](https://edri.org/campaign/support-digital-rights-europe/) URL. When I login to PayPal and make a payment, I get the following message
[image]

I do have the backend code and here is what it looks like.

```
<?php
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '../vendor/autoload.php';

/**
* Edri PayPal Pyment
*/
class Edri_PayPal_Payment
{
    
    private $api;

    private $payer;

    private $details;

    private $amount;

    private $transaction;

    private $payment;

    private $redirectUrls;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->api = $this->setup_PayPal_Api();
    }

    private function debug($val)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($val);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    private function setup_PayPal_Api()
    {
        $api = new ApiContext(
            new OAuthTokenCredential(
                'MyPayPalClientID',
                'MyClientSecret'
            )
        );

        $api->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => 'live',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'Log.LogEnabled' => false,
            'Log.FileName' => '',
            'Log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
            'validation.level' => 'log'
        ));

        return $api;
    }

    private function setupPayer()
    {
        $this->payer = new Payer();

        $this->payer->setPayment_method('paypal');
    }

    private function setupDetails($amount)
    {
        $this->details = new Details();
        $this->details->setShipping('0.00')
            ->setTax('0.00')
            ->setsubTotal($amount);
    }

    private function setupAmount($amount)
    {

        $this->amount = new Amount();

        $this->amount->setCurrency('EUR')
            ->setTotal($amount)
            ->setDetails($this->details);
    }
    
    private function setupTransaction($amount)
    {

        $this->transaction = new Transaction();

        $this->transaction->setAmount($this->amount)
            ->setDescription('Make a donation of €' . $amount .  ' to EDRi');
    }
    
    private function setupPayment()
    {
        $this->payment = new Payment();

        $this->payment->setIntent('sale')
            ->setPayer($this->payer)
            ->setTransactions(array($this->transaction))
            ->setRedirectUrls($this->redirectUrls);
    }

    private function setupRedirectUrls()
    {
        $this->redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();

        $this->redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('https://edri.org/payment?pppa=true')
            ->setCancelUrl('https://edri.org/payment?pppa=false');
    }

    public function prepare_payment ($paymentCredtials) {
        $amount = str_replace(',', '', number_format($paymentCredtials['edriPayment_amount'], 2));

        $this->setupPayer();
        $this->setupDetails($amount);
        $this->setupAmount($amount);
        $this->setupTransaction($amount);
        $this->setupRedirectUrls();
        $this->setupPayment();  

        try {

            $this->payment->create($this->api);

            $paymentID = $this->payment->getId();
        
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->log($e);
            
            header('Location: https://edri.org/donation-oops');

            return false;
        }

        return $paymentID;

    }

    private function log($log){

        $file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '../logs/paypal_log.txt';


        // Open the file to get existing content
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        // Append a new person to the file
        $current .=  $prefix . ' ' . date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()) . ' //// ' . "\n";
        $current .=  self::var_dump_str($log) . "\n";
        // Write the contents back to the file
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
    }

    public function execute_payment($paymentCredentials)
    {
        $this->debug($paymentCredentials);

        $payment = Payment::get($paymentCredentials['paymentId'], $this->api);

        $execution = new PaymentExecution();

        $execution->setPayerId($paymentCredentials['PayerID']);


        try {

            echo $payment->execute($execution, $this->api);
        
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->log($e);
            
            header('Location: https://edri.org/donation-oops');

            return false;
        }

        return $payment->state = 'approved' ? true : false;
        
    }

    public function kickoff_payment()
    {

        foreach ($this->payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if ($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirectUrl = $link->getHref();
            }
        }

        header('Location: ' . $redirectUrl);
    }

}
```

I checked the logs, nothing is reported. API calls seems to be fine as well.

Any suggestion to make this work would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please first verify your paypal account by [this way](http://www.wikihow.com/Verify-a-PayPal-Account). If your code is ok then may be this step could be solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

There's a possibility that the `var_dump()` statements you have are violating the *"no content output before header" rule* and therefore, the user's payment flow stops with your code, before the `header('Location: ' . $redirectUrl);` can redirect to PayPal to finish the job.

Try removing those `var_dump`s, and doing `error_log(printf($val, true))` instead, as not to interrupt the call to `header()`.

**Edit** - From http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.
>
> ```
> <html>
> <?php
> /* This will give an error. Note the output
>  * above, which is before the header() call */
> header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
> exit;
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Hi @cameron-hurd You mean I should var_dump($val) of the above code and replace it with error_log(printf($val, true))

Comment: That's right - `error_log` doesn't output anything, and passing `true` as a second argument to `printf` returns, rather than outputs the value. If content before output is the problem, this will let you sidestep that while still examining the variable's values.

Comment: I did the replace and now it prints just the word "Array" instead of the previous message (which is in the figure) :(

Comment: I see you've got a `var_dump_str` function on this class somewhere... is that being called? Could it be outputting the `Array` text? The name of the game is to find the source of the output in order to test the thesis that `header()` is failing to redirect the user.

Comment: I am calling in the front-end page as $current .=  self::var_dump_str($log) . "\n";

And it is defined as follows
static function var_dump_str()
 {
     $argc = func_num_args();
     $argv = func_get_args();

     if ($argc > 0) {
         ob_start();
         call_user_func_array('var_dump', $argv);
         $result = ob_get_contents();
         ob_end_clean();
         return $result;
     }

     return '';
 }

Comment: Try commenting it out for now - for the same reason above. We want to avoid output in order to see if that's preventing the client from being redirected by the `header()` call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124908/discussion-between-cameron-hurd-and-kingmakerking).